# Internal of .NET timer controller

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

In VB.NET or C#, windows form applications can be added a timer controller to run tasks in scheduled manner. But what is the internal implementation of a timer? Does it use a separate thread for each timer? or Thread pool? or other concurrent programming paradigm?

**EDIT**

Additionally, I want to know does the timer controller satisfy concurrent safty property as described below?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    i = i + 1 //Line 1
              //Line 2, some code is here will takes some cpu time
    i = i - 1 //Line 3
              //Line 4, some code is here; takes another cpu time
End Sub
```

Can we guarantee that public variable `i` always have the values 1 or 0?

Comment: there are different kinds of timers, which one do you mean? and why not check [reference code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)?

Comment: @LeiYang Post this as the answer. This is what I expected (reference code).

Comment: If you want to see the implementation, go to [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Timer.cs,21e9545cfe31887d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Forms timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) will run on the UI thread (it will post timer events to the main event loop).

The `System.Timers.Timer` will by default use the thread pool for timer events.

To answer your updated question: Assuming you are using the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, the tick handler will always run to completion before the next tick event is run (since they always run on the same thread). Don't forget to wrap in try/finally though.

Comment: "Don't forget to wrap in try/finally though." - Why?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx): "A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. **It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread**." (emphasis mine)

So it runs in the same thread as your app, and it somehow gets the windows message pump to raise its `Tick` event at regular intervals. If the code inside the `Tick` event takes a while to run, your app won't update its UI until it finishes. You can get yourself into all sorts of trouble using `DoEvents` to let the UI update during a long-running `Tick` event, but I'd recommend using a `BackgroundWorker` instead - it is a little more difficult to code, but easier to get it right.

Comment: Just be aware that there is more than one `Timer` class in .NET. Only the Windows Forms timer is driven by the main event loop.

Comment: The original question mentioned the windows forms "timer controller" specifically.